# Java Data Format Error

Tags: java, datetime

Any Clues on how to fix this:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd hh:24mi:ss");
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'i'
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.compile(SimpleDateFormat.java:696)
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.initialize(SimpleDateFormat.java:515)
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:464)
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:445)
at CopyEJ.CopyEJ.main(CopyEJ.java:105)
```

Comment: what are you trying to do?  what do you expect 'i' format character to do?

Comment: can  u show us the date string

Comment: What is the **expected** result?

Comment: Your date pattern looks like Oracle database and not like Java...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your date format pattern string contains the invalid sequence `24mi`.

change to:

```
SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
```

note:
the Big letter "HH" means 24 hours: e.g 23:59:00
while "hh" is 12 hours format: 11:59:00

Answer (score 7):

Your pattern string is not following the java standard. This should work:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 2):

As pointed by others, the pattern string is not correct, and can be as showed by others `"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"`.

Refer the [java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for looking up the available pattern letters that could be used for formatting a date.

Snippet from the above link

```
Letter  Date or Time Component  Presentation    Examples
G   Era designator  Text    AD
y   Year    Year    1996; 96
M   Month in year   Month   July; Jul; 07
w   Week in year    Number  27
W   Week in month   Number  2
D   Day in year     Number  189
d   Day in month    Number  10
F   Day of week in month    Number  2
E   Day in week     Text    Tuesday; Tue
a   Am/pm marker    Text    PM
H   Hour in day (0-23)  Number  0
k   Hour in day (1-24)  Number  24
K   Hour in am/pm (0-11)    Number  0
h   Hour in am/pm (1-12)    Number  12
m   Minute in hour  Number  30
s   Second in minute    Number  55
S   Millisecond     Number  978
z   Time zone   General time zone   Pacific Standard Time; PST; GMT-08:00
Z   Time zone   RFC 822 time zone   -0800
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want hours in 24 hour format
Use this

```
    DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date dd=new Date();
    System.out.println(df.format(dd));
```